# How to Mirror weights from one side to other for group of vertex groups?

Tags: bones, workflow, weight-painting, mirror, vertex-groups

I need that, but do that in one step for group of bones without manually work with bone by bone at vertex group tab.
[image: What i need]

One of the solutions, but it is suitable when you need to make this action for a maximum of a pair of bones or a little more, but when will there be more? It won't be convenient.

[image: The way to do it]